# Renaming text files based on a keyword inside the files

Tags: tasker, automation, scripts

I have many files inside a folder with `.txt` extension. Now they are named randomly by an app but I want to rename each text file to some words written in those files itself after words `Name:` but before word `Age:`.

**Example**

A file named `13765_46748.txt` contains:

```
This is just a test file containing info of each persons.
Name: Pearson Bratts Age: 55 Profession:Technician
```

Now I want the above file to be renamed to `Pearson Bratts.txt` using Tasker or any other script app with working script.

Answer (score 1):

The complete **shell** script follows. You need a **Terminal emulator**, but I'll leave that to you.

---

```
if [ "$1" == "$(cat /dev/null)" ]; then
 echo "Usage: $0 <file>"
 return 1
fi

content="$(cat '$1')"
content="${content#*Name: }"
content="${content// Age*/}"

mv "$1" "$content.txt"
```

---

This is to be saved in a **something.sh**, which, when executed, will require an additional parameter. For example, we'll assume you'll call it **renamer.sh**, and thus the usage will be:

```
renamer.sh some/file.txt
```

. It'll rename the file you give it, accordingly to its content. **To give it the correct file, is your responsibility, and it works for only a file per execution. It won't work if the file has spaces inside its name.**